# Is there any way to get the estimate cost of executing a query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

In PostgreSQL, EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE will show the estimate cost of executing a query. But EXPLAIN in MySQL doesn't provide this information. How can I get the estimate cost without installation of other tools? I'm using MySQL-5.6.16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't much out there for MySQL except the following:

- [**EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-extended.html)
- [**SHOW PROFILES (Older Releases of MySQL)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profiles.html)
- [**MySQL PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html)

Read these carefully, see what you think ...

Comment: Also note that while query cost isn't returned in the basic EXPLAIN command, it is available if instead you use EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON

Answer (score 10):

In short

1. Run your `SELECT ...` query
2. `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'last_query_cost'`
3. if the answer was 0 rerun the query with 
   `select  SQL_NO_CACHE ...` and do step 2 above again